# Библиотека для работы С#

Tags: c#

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить проблему

> Предупреждение    1   Не удается разрешить
> основную ссылку
> "D:\диплом1\Транспортная 
> задача\Транспортная
> задача\MyLibrary\bin\Debug\MyLibrary.dll",
> поскольку она была построена для
> платформы
> ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5". Это
> более поздняя версия по сравнению с
> текущей целевой платформой
> ".NETFramework,Version=v3.5". lab1

Из-за чего это?

Comment: Небось библиотеку и основную программу с разными версиями Visual Studio компилировали?

Comment: может это из за того что я работаю VisualStudio 2012, а MSSQL у меня 2008

Answer (score 4):

Это значит, что вы создали проект в C#, который использует .NET-Framework версии 3.5, а библиотека была скомпилированна при помощи .NET 4.5 и соответственно может пытаться использовать функции присущие этой версии фрэймворка.

Из-за того, что вы работаете в VisualStudio 2012, а MSSQL у вас 2008 роли никакой не играет. Не смешивайте разные вещи в кучу.

Либо скомпилируйте библиотеку под 3.5 либо свой проект переключите в свойствах проекта на версию 4.5.

Answer (score 2):

Единственное что видно - это конфликт платформ. Что пишете, на какой студии, какой дот нет стоит?

попробуйте почитать  [тут](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ff657133(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: может это из за того что я работаю VisualStudio 2012, а MSSQL у меня 2008